# Is it possible to install a wildcard certificate without the private key on Tomcat?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, keytool

I received following files from another department in my company which I am supposed to install on my Tomcat 8.5 Webserver in order to activate HTTPS and use TLS/SSL:

- csr.pem
- ca.pem
- intermediate.pem
- certificate.crt

Most tutorials I found online guide through the process of creating the keystore, generating a CSR and installing the certificate received afterwards. My company wishes to use it's wildcard certificate, so the certificate and related files exist already.

I tried to generate a new keystore with my own private key & import ca, intermediate & certificate in it, but I'm getting an error which says that the public key doesn't match with my keystore.

I guess, this is because I need to import the private key used to generate the CSR before. But since I don't have it, I want to make sure - is it possible to install the certificate without the private key (respectively generating my own private key) or did they possible forget to send it along?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard or not, a certificate without its associated private key is useless.

As they are used in asymetrical cryptography, operations need the public key (contained in the certificate) and the private key (stored separately).

And they are generated together, you can not have a certificate and then later on generate a new key and associate with it. A CSR, which later becomes a certificate, includes some information derived from the private key.